# Error in javascript - Replace hash tags with links

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

**I have the following problem:**

I have a simple **View.py:**

```
def Article_view_2(request):
    return render_to_response('articles.html', {'articles': Event.objects.all()})
```

There is an **HTML** part where I output all the data from the model to get a news line:

```
{% block name %}
        {% for event in articles %}
            <img src="{{ event.cover_event.url}} " width="300px">
            <h4>{{ event.author }}</h4>
            <h6>{{ event.event_date|date:'F j' }}</h6>
            <h4>{{ event.event_title }}</h4>
            <div class="item">
                <p>{{ event.event_text }}</p>
            </div>
            <p>{{ event.event_a }}</p><p>{{ event.event_b }}</p><p>{{ event.event_c }}</p>
            <h1>{{ event.all_rate }}</h1>
            <h2>{{ event.index }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock  %}
```

I also use the **javascript** code to replace **#hastags** with links:

```
var str = $('.item p').html(),
  regex = /(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!\d+(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/gi;

function replacer(hash){
  var replacementString = $.trim(hash);
  return ' <a href="https://www.example.com/'+ replacementString +'" target="_blank">' + replacementString + '</a>';
}
$('.item p').html( str.replace( regex , replacer ) );
```

But when I open the page, I get the same description - **{{event.event_text}}** - for all posts.

**What's my mistake???**

Comment: The rest of the info is show up eg the author and date?

Comment: @TimCodes, Yes, everything else works correctly. Only {{event.event_text}} become the same for all posts

Comment: Just to clarify, too, is the literal `{{ event.event_text }}` showing up, or is it same value that's showing up? In other words, is it a single event's event_text that is showing up over and over again, or is it actually displaying `{{ event.event_text }}`?

Comment: If I do not connect the JavaScript code, HTML prints different {{event.event_text}} from all posts. If I connect javascript, HTML outputs the same value for all posts. He takes the {{event.event_text}} value from the first post and gives it to all the other posts

Comment: Sorry for my English)

Comment: my guess is you have a problem with a closure please psot the rest of your js code that does something with the event text

Comment: This is the entire text of the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector will apply the same code to all items targeted, you could use a loop like below to replace the links one by one :

```
$( '.item p' ).each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex, replacer));
});
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you very much! the evening ends just fine

Comment: @JohnDoe haha thanks for the feedback, good evening ! without regex nightmares